# Set decimal precision in SQL CLR function in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR function written in C# that goes something like:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString Decimal(decimal sum)
    {
        return sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

And SQL Server assumes that 'sum' is a `numeric(18,0)` type.

Is there a way to change the precision and scale of an input parameter in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precision and scale can be specified using [SQLFacet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfacetattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) attributes. For example, `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFacet(Precision = ..., Scale = ...)] ...`

Comment: Isn't sql facet used for return types and not input variables?

Comment: You're right, the documentation does imply that, but it can be used on inputs as well. Just decorate the input parameter inline

Comment: @Tomas and allmhuran: +1 for `SqlFacet`, though I don't think there's an implication that `SqlFacet` is only for input or output. It is definitely intended for both, even if the examples are lacking. Also, please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62776976/577765) for additional options, that can be in addition to, or in place of, `SqlFacet` (I often do both).

Comment: Yes, to be honest that's really the better answer even if you aren't using unsupported options, because of devops pipelines and so on.

Comment: allmhuran (and @Tomas ): speaking of DevOps, I just added a note to my answer regarding **BinaryFormatter**.

Comment: allmhuran (and @Tomas ): Also, just FYI: when there are more than 2 people in comments on a question or answer, you need to use the `@` name for the non-poster of that question/answer to get notified, and you can only do 1 `@` name. No need to do that for the poster of the question/answer as they are always notified.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Haha, that's exactly what made me think of devops, I have used your utility on and off for a while now, thanks :)

Comment: allmhuran: That's awesome. You are quite welcome. I'm glad that it's being useful for you 

Answer (score 2):

While allmhuran is not incorrect regarding `SqlFacet`, please understand that `SqlFacet`, at least for the `Precision` and `Scale` properties (and at least some, but maybe not all, other properties) is used by Visual Studio / SSDT to auto-generate the DLL for publishing. Meaning, you do not need to rely on `SqlFacet` if you write your own `CREATE` statements. Using SSDT to do this is great for initial development / testing, but `SqlFacet` doesn't support all the options you might want to set, such as parameter defaults and/or something like `WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` (used for Scalar UDFs). For example:

- ```sql
  CREATE FUNCTION [schema_name].[function_name]
  (
    @param1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @param2 DECIMAL(17, 9)
  )
  RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
  WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER,
       RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  AS EXTERNAL NAME [assembly].[class].[method];
  ```
- ```sql
  CREATE PROCEDURE [schema_name].[proc_name]
      @param1 NVARCHAR(4000) = N'default value',
      @param2 DECIMAL(17, 9) = 123.456789
  WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS EXTERNAL NAME [assembly].[class].[method];
  ```

ALSO:

- If you are creating the objects manually, you will still need the `VARBINARY` literal representation of the DLL for the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement (the assumption being that Visual Studio is used to compile the assembly but not using it / SSDT to generate the publish SQL script). For this you can use a simple, open-source command line utility I wrote: [BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/sqlquantumleap/binaryformatter)
- You should be using `SqlDecimal` as the input type instead of `decimal`. You then get the actual `decimal` value from the param using the `Value` property:

  ```cs
  public static SqlString Decimal([SqlFacet(Precision = ..., Scale = ..)] 
  SqlDecimal sum)
  {
     decimal theValue = sum.Value;
  }
  ```

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)